# Android application not restoring state when installed from .apk, works fine from eclipse

Tags: android, restore

This is very strange: when I test my app installed from Eclipse, it is restoring it's state just fine, eg it shows the correct activity/ screen after moving away from the app and then tapping the icon again. 
This does not work when I install the exact same code from an exported .apk file: the app comes back "blank", starting with the login screen.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Some code related to this would help

Comment: I'm sorry, I wouldnt even know what part of the code. Android should remember the activity stack and keep all object states over the lifecycle of the app.

Comment: I have the same problem with restoring ViewPager. @Ascorbin did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you click "run" button in Eclipse it does not means that application is really installed. It may just returns to screen in last state. This happens when you do not make any changes in code since last run.

When you really install app (by eclipse / from apk / by adb) android first stops already running old app, then reinstall it and runs from very beginning (login screen in your case). It is valid behavior and you can not change it.

If you have some data (eg logins or passwords), that should be saved through installs or updates you should use [backup servie](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html). It will work even if you install app to another device.

Comment: I know what you mean but I can rule that out. When I run the app from eclipse, it IS installed. Restoring the state works fine when I use the app from there on. I also dont mean restoring data after the app was akilled or the device was rebooted, but only when the app was pushed to the background and then called again.