# Android is always starting with splashscreen when pressing shortcut

Tags: android

I have a strange effect on my Nexus S where I also develop with: 
When producing a release signed version of my app and I install this on the device the app is sometimes not keeping it's state, means it always restarts with the splashscreen when pressing the apps shortcut. 
When starting the app via menu it is OK it shows the last activity.
After a rebbot of the phone the shortcut start is ok again.

Does someone have the same effect or some explaination for this ?

Comment: what is launch mode of activities... ?

Comment: I think I know what you mean, I had something similar once: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523301/android-application-not-restoring-state-when-installed-from-apk-works-fine-fro

Comment: Have You any logs? Probably sometimes it get unloaded?

Comment: @Ascorbin and how did you solve this ?

Comment: @Jitendra launch mode is not specified, so it should be standard by default

Comment: @freakdev I didn't, it was on some test app and never occured again.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rely on Android, when it comes to keeping application state between two launches. Numerous things may happen, including low memory state, forced restart, phone restart, timeout and so on. In most cases, when you close your application, Android will destroy all activities to reclaim some memory the app took.

Also, you can check your phone setting. There is an option 'don't keep activities', which will simply destroy any inactive activity automaticly.

Comment: I know this but I'm talking about starting the app pressing the home key and imediately trying to resume. If the Activity would be destroyed it would show the same effect, either restarting through menu or shortcut.